# clsql trouble in SBCL

Tags: mysql, common-lisp, sbcl, clsql

I'm trying to get clsql working (used to use cl-mysql, but looking at alternatives). Just attempting to play around at this point, and I'm getting stopped at `connect`

```
(connect '("localhost" "test" "user" "password") :database-type :mysql)
```

gets me

```
erred while invoking #<COMPILE-OP (:VERBOSE NIL) {BDFF0B9}> on
#<CLSQL-UFFI-SOURCE-FILE "clsql-uffi" "uffi" "clsql_uffi">
   [Condition of type ASDF:OPERATION-ERROR]

Backtrace:
  0: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF:PERFORM (ASDF:COMPILE-OP CLSQL-UFFI-SYSTEM::CLSQL-UFFI-SOURCE-FILE)) ..)
  1: ((LAMBDA (SB-PCL::.PV. SB-PCL::.NEXT-METHOD-CALL. SB-PCL::.ARG0. SB-PCL::.ARG1.)) ..)
  2: ((LAMBDA ()))
  3: ((FLET SB-THREAD::WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK-THUNK))
  4: ((FLET #:WITHOUT-INTERRUPTS-BODY-[CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK]324))
  5: (SB-THREAD::CALL-WITH-RECURSIVE-LOCK ..)
  6: ((FLET SB-C::WITH-IT))
  7: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD ASDF:OPERATE (T T)) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> ASDF:LOAD-OP :CLSQL-MYSQL)[:EXTERNAL]
  8: ((LAMBDA (SB-PCL::.PV. SB-PCL::.NEXT-METHOD-CALL. SB-PCL::.ARG0. SB-PCL::.ARG1. SB-INT:&MORE SB-PCL::.DFUN-MORE-CONTEXT. SB-PCL::.DFUN-MORE-COUNT.)) ..)
  9: (CONNECT ("localhost" "test" "user" "password"))[:EXTERNAL]
 10: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CONNECT '("localhost" "test" "user" "password") :DATABASE-TYPE :MYSQL) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
 11: ((LAMBDA ()))
 --more--
```

If I follow the `accept` restarts (trimmed above for brevity) all the way through, I eventually get to

```
Attempt to call an undefined alien function.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL::UNDEFINED-ALIEN-FUNCTION-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME interactive evaluation request.
 1: [ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [TERMINATE-THREAD] Terminate this thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {BD63789}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-KERNEL::UNDEFINED-ALIEN-FUNCTION-ERROR)
  1: ("foreign function: #x806774B")
  2: ("foreign function: #x8052F2D")
  3: ("foreign function: #x80565C9")
  4: ((SB-PCL::FAST-METHOD CLSQL-SYS:DATABASE-CONNECT (T (EQL :MYSQL))) #<unavailable argument> #<unavailable argument> ("localhost" "test" "user" "password") :MYSQL)
  5: (CONNECT ("localhost" "test" "user" "password"))[:EXTERNAL]
  6: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CONNECT '("localhost" "test" "user" "password") :DATABASE-TYPE :MYSQL) #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  7: ((LAMBDA ()))
 --more--
```

I'm using SBCL 1.0.40.0, Debian 6.0, `clsql` was installed using `quicklisp` and mysql v14.14 (although I doubt this is an issue with mysql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had to do

```
apt-get install cl-sql
```

This was necessary despite the fact that I already had `libmysqlclient-dev` and had installed `clsql` through quicklisp (which looked like it had all the correct c files with it). After doing this, I was able to connect to a local mysql server using

```
(connect '("localhost" "test" "user" "password") :database-type :mysql)
```

As a note, it still threw a couple warnings on my 64-bit system (no problems on my 32 bit machine); using the `accept` restart (sorry, Xach) got it to a seemingly working state.

I have no idea how, in detail, this fixed the problem; if someone can explain it, answer and I'll upvote+accept (assuming your explanation is correct).

EDIT: Similar problem on another machine had me frustrated for about 30 minutes. It seems like this should be assumed, but **if you're building a system from bare metal, make sure you install `gcc`**. If you don't, it prevents `clsql-uffi` from compiling its components for obvious reasons. When the process fails this way, you get the same compilation error as in the question, so cover your bases.

Comment: In general Debian modifies CL libraries in ways that I find confusing and hard to troubleshoot. I use Debian systems, but for Lisp libraries and implementation, I get everything from upstream or Quicklisp. Not really an explanation, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `accept` restart. It means "Keep going even though something is screwed up," and that's rarely if ever what you want to do.

Do you have the mysql development libraries installed? Do you have libmysqlclient.so?

One thing to try: start a fresh sbcl and quickload "clsql-uffi", then trace `clsql-uffi::find-and-load-foreign-library`, then `(clsql:connect nil :database-type 'mysql)` to see if it's finding what you need, based on the trace output.

Comment: I have `libmysqlclient-dev` installed, `find -name libmysqlclient.so` returns a match in `/usr/lib/`. Qickloading `clsql-uffi` on a clean SBCL fails with the same errors I have above (qickloading `uffi` succeeds, and quickloading `clsql_uffi` gives me a `System not found` error. If I try quickloading `clsql-uffi` after `clsql_uffi`, it errors telling me that `CLSQL-UFFI:ATOL64` is undefined).

Comment: Loading `clsql-uffi-loader.lisp` manually also gives an error; `Couldn't load foreign library "clsql_uffi". (searched CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*)`. `CLSQL-SYS:*FOREIGN-LIBRARY-SEARCH-PATHS*` evaluates to `(#P"/home/inaimathi/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/clsql-20101207-git/uffi/")` (which is correct, and that directory contains `clsql_uffi` files `lib`, `c` and `dll`). I get the feeling I'm missing something small and obvious.